# Get only schema in dbt sources.yml

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, jinja2, dbt

I am using dbt in our data pipelines. I have this sources.yml and I want to return only `<database>.<schema>` like `my_project.my_schema`

How do I do that using Jinja?

```
sources:
  - name: my_source
    schema: my_schema
    description: My database
    database: my_project

    tables:
      - name: items
```

Comment: What did you try? Do you have a reproductible sample?

Comment: I did the `{{ source('my_source', 'items') }}` but it would return up to the table name

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Let's use `include` method in the `Relation` dbt Classes

```sql
{{ source('my_source', 'items').include(identifier=False) }}
```

Similarly if you'd like to exclude:

- database: `{{ source('my_source', 'items').include(database=False) }}`
- schema: `{{ source('my_source', 'items').include(schema=False) }}`

But anyway, I'm curious of what purpose is?
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The `source` macro returns a `Relation` object in Jinja (https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-classes#relation). Just use that to output what you're looking for:

```
{% set src_rel = source('my_source', 'items') %}
{{ src_rel.database }}.{{ src_rel.schema }}
```